# Finding invert for complicated function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

I'm looking for an invert for this function (when x > 0): [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log((x*x%2B9)%2F(x*x))*sqrt((3*x-x*x*atan(3%2Fx))%2Fatan(3%2Fx))%2F(-2*x*atan(3%2Fx)%2B6))

Just wondering if there is any chance it exists..

Maybe some numerical methods could help finding it?

Comment: Newton-Raphson?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is
$f(x)
=log((x*x+9)/(x*x))*sqrt((3*x-x*x*atan(3/x))/atan(3/x))/(-2*x*atan(3/x)+6)\\
=\log\left(\dfrac{x^2+9}{x^2}\right)\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{3x-x^2\arctan(3/x)}{\arctan(3/x)}}}{-2x\arctan(3/x)+6}\\
=\log\left(1+\dfrac{9}{x^2}\right)\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{3x}{\arctan(3/x)}-x^2}}{-2x\arctan(3/x)+6}\\
=\log\left(1+(3/x)^2\right)\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{x\arctan(3/x)}-1}}{-2\arctan(3/x)+6/x}\\
=\frac12\log\left(1+(3/x)^2\right)\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{x\arctan(3/x)}-1}}{-\arctan(3/x)+3/x}\\
$

Letting
$3/x=y$, so $x = 3/y$,

$f(3/y)
=\frac12\log\left(1+y^2\right)\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{\arctan(y)}-1}}{-\arctan(y)+y}\\
=\frac12\log\left(1+y^2\right)\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{y-\arctan(y)}{\arctan(y)}}}{y-\arctan(y)}\\
=\frac12\log\left(1+y^2\right)\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{\arctan(y)(y-\arctan(y))}}\\
=\dfrac{\log\left(1+y^2\right)}{2\sqrt{\arctan(y)(y-\arctan(y))}}\\
$

Letting $y = \tan(z)$,

$f(3/\tan(z))
=\dfrac{\log\left(1+\tan^2(z)\right)}{2\sqrt{z(\tan(z)-z)}}\\
$

Considering that
$\tan(z)-z$
can't be inverted
(at least I don't think it can),
there is,
in my opinion,
no hope of
inverting this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for doing this! I also don't think it can be inverted directly because it is symmetrical about the Y. Was just thinking maybe it makes any difference that we limit the argument to be always positive.